# I can't find where my errors are

Tags: c#

I get two errors "Cannot assign to 'C' because it's a 'foreach iteration variable" and "Syntax error, value expected" I don't really know where my error is? I can get some fresh on eyes to ID my deficiency.

```
int[] numDictionary = new int[] { 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 1 };

IDictionary<int, int> count = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();    
//count = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
//int SortedDictionary = count;

foreach (var c in numDictionary)
{
    if (c > 0)
    {
        count[c] = count.[c] + 1;
    }

}
//return count.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(count);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `count` is a dictionary. `c` is an int. Can't assign `count` to `c`. Also, as the error says, it's a loop variable. You cannot change it: that's the loop's job.

Comment: And you're creating `count` twice. And what's `count[c] = c[] +1` supposed to do? Perhaps you should to read some tutorials. Learn about types, arrays, etc.

Comment: It is not really clear what you wish to do from either your description or the code that you have posted.

Comment: I suppose to write a program that counts, in a given array of integers and the number of occurrences of each integer.

Comment: This is part of online course that i'm taking and I slowly find myself struggle to get through. I was very reluctant on taking an online course but it was the  only coding class. i could take at the moment.

Comment: You cannot do ***count[c] = count.[c] + 1;*** You can only do this when your SortedDictionary has items. Right now, it's empty. You just declared it but it does not have any items in it.

Answer (score 0):

In a `foreach` loop you don't access the contents of the collection by an index. You directly address the collection items using the iteration variable you defined (in this case, `var c`).

```
Console.WriteLine("Contents of numDictionary: ");
foreach (var c in numDictionary)
{
    Console.Write(c);
}
```

However, an iteration variable cannot be modified - it can only be read. If you want to iterate over the array and modify the contents, use a `for` loop.

```
int[] numDictionary = new int[] { 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 1 };

for (int i = 0; i < numDictionary.Length; ++i)
{
    numDictionary[i] = numDictionary[i] + 1;
}
```

You can find out more about the `foreach` statement and how it relates to the `for` statement in [this Microsoft Development Network article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).